# Place underscore in font-face

Tags: css, font-face, font-family

I am writing a utility that needs to show people the font faces they have installed on their machines. I have found that you can't do it via java (without a lot of work, and security issues), CMD or Powershell, VBasic (redundant). But ...

I eventually found that you can export the registry fonts list, and by filtering with javascript, can get the names and *.ttf / *otf data. You can then built a series of @font-face groups, listing the font-family as the name, and src:local as the *.ttf name.

Again, by experimenting, I found this approach works fine with 'complete' filenames, such as 'aliee13.ttf', 'bobcat.ttf', 'bnmachine.ttf' etc. But ...

When you get something like "Ameth___.ttf", the underscores seem to throw it. I have tried "Ameth\_\_\_.ttf", "AmethU+005FU+005FU+005F.ttf", but I can't find the work around.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: "Alien Encounters";
  src: local(aliee13.ttf);
 font-weight: bold;
color:red;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "BN Machine";
  src: local(bnmachine.ttf);
 font-weight: bold;
color:red;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Bobcat";
  src: local(bobcat.ttf);
color:red;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Amethyst Regular";
  src: local("Ameth___.ttf");
color:red;
}

h1{font-family:"Alien Encounters"}
h2{font-family:"BN Machine"}
h3{font-family:"Bobcat"}
h4{font-family:"Amethyst Regular"}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Will this text show correctly?</h1>
<h2>This should be Autumn</h2>
<h3>This should be Bobcat</h3>
<h4>This should be Amethyst ??</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

If you try it, you'll see the first three render fine. The third appears in 'default' Arial or similar. If "push comes to shove", I can 'eliminate' any files with one or more underscores ... but I'd like to get it correct if I can.

NB: Gonna be quite a style file as I have about 500 fonts on my machine !

Comment: Just looked at the file regedit exported ... and it has added lots of "00" to the hex code.  So whereas the filename might show as"5F5F5F"(dot.ttf) the export saves it as "5F005F005F00" (and ditto with every other entry adding 00 after the hex code ???

Comment: The file starts with FF FE ... and apparently, this is called a BOM, and I need to convert from UTF16LE to UTF8 (Although that still don't help much!)

Comment: Solved it. There is a little utility called "iconv" within CMD that will convert between the two. Here is the command, (path relative to the folder I was in) "C:\Users\Cxxxx Bxxxx>iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 desktop\font_files.txt > desktop
\fixed.txt" ... So now I've got to see if I can 'grab' the font registry entry, (paste it to desktop), convert to correct format, and open HTML page in browser ... all from within a "*.bat" file" ! (The user then clicks button so FileReader reads file into textarea and JS process) (Will leave 'open' lest anyone wants to add their ideas.

Comment: Seems it's only the file that is exported from the registry that is in UTF-16LE format. I found this command - which has a different output layout, and does not include the font-family name - but does so in UTF-8 "dir \ C:\WINDOWS\Fonts >FontList.txt"